# Formating a text files using batch script

Tags: windows, batch-file, dos

I have a file with the following content.

```
http://server.in.oracle.com:18080/svn/SVN_DEMO/branches/CI_TEST/AM/SQL/ampks_amdtronl_kernel.sql
http://server.in.oracle.com:18080/svn/SVN_DEMO/branches/CI_TEST/AM/SQL/ampks_amdtronl_utils.sql
http://server.in.oracle.com:18080/svn/SVN_DEMO/branches/CI_TEST/AM/SQL/ampks_fundupload.sql
http://server.in.oracle.com:18080/svn/SVN_DEMO/branches/CI_TEST/AM/SQL/ampks_amdtronl_main.sql
http://server.in.oracle.com:18080/svn/SVN_DEMO/branches/CI_TEST/AM/SQL/ampks_validate.sql
```

I need a batch script to format the file in such a way that it will look like the following.

```
ampks_amdtronl_kernel.sql:AM/SQL/ampks_amdtronl_kernel.sql
ampks_amdtronl_utils.sql:AM/SQL/ampks_amdtronl_utils.sql
ampks_fundupload.sql:AM/SQL/ampks_fundupload.sql
ampks_amdtronl_main.sql:AM/SQL/ampks_amdtronl_main.sql
ampks_validate.sql:AM/SQL/ampks_validate.sql
```

Thats is filename:Path/from/AM/till/filname

Kindly guide.

Answer (score 1):

```
for /f %%a in (file.txt) do echo %%~nxa:AM/SQL/%%~nxa >>temp.txt
del file.txt /f /q
ren temp.txt file.txt
```

Comment: Are you running it in a batch file or from a cmd prompt? It works fine for me.

Comment: Then it should be fine, are you using my exact answer? If not can you post here or edit your question with the exact batch code you are using.

Comment: The command is working fine now. But I have other folders also like AM. SVN_DEMO/branches/CI_TEST/MAIN/AM/SQL/ampks_validate.sql
SVN_DEMO/branches/CI_TEST/MAIN/AM/VW/amvw_fund_online_summary.vw
SVN_DEMO/branches/CI_TEST/MAIN/BC/SQL/bcpks_lcdefault.sql   This one will not work if we are giving AM/SQL in the command

Comment: Then you would need to ask another question if you have more variables to take into consideration as the end answer could be quite a bit different. Just ask another question detailing the possibilities that could change.

Comment: Thanks.. I made it with something like for /f %%a in (file.txt) do (

echo %%~nxa:%%a >>temp.txt
)

Answer (score 0):

In a loop of your choice:
1. Split the line into two

```
suffix=${line##.*/AM}   # this deletes everything before /AM so you have the suffix
fname=`basename $line`  # this gives you the name of the file
```

1. reassemble the pieces as you wish with

   echo "${fname}:${sufffix}"

Alternatively, you can do it with a single line of `sed`.

Answer (score 0):

You may use awk to accomplish this. 
Or use simple text editor to replace http://server.in.oracle.com:18080/svn/SVN_DEMO/branches/CI_TEST with empty string.
Then, we can import the file to Excel to divide the string into columns on '/' 
Finally, use concatenate function (in Excel) to build your string.

I would prefer awk, you need to use split function

> awk '{split($0,a,"/"); print a[10],':',a[6],'/',a[7],'/',a[8],'/',a[9],'/',a[10]}'`

Answer (score 0):

PowerShell to the rescue:

```
param ([string] $inFileName, [string] $outFileName)

function Reformat-String
{
    param (
        [string] $str
    )

    $split = $str.Split("/")

    return $split[9] + ":" + $split[7] + "/" + $split[8] + "/" + $split[9]
}

$file = Get-Content $inFileName

foreach($line in $file)
{
    $newLine = Reformat-String $line
    $newLine | Out-File $outFileName -Append
}
```

Saved as "reformat.ps1". Invoke as .\reformat.ps1 SourceFilePath DestinationFilePath

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off
For /F "tokens=7-9 delims=/" %%a in (thefile.txt) do echo %%c:%%a/%%b/%%c
```